# RxSwift crash EXC_BAD_ACCESS, when OnNext called on subject

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I have a weird crash that I managed to reproduce in skeleton app.
I have a framework which uses RxSwift az a cocoapod dependency.
It has a simple class defined:

```
public final class FWSupplier {
    public let psubject = PublishSubject<Int>()
    public let bsubject = BehaviorSubject<Int>(value: 0)
    public init() { }
    public func triggerBehaviour() {
        self.bsubject.onNext(1)
    }

    public func triggerPublish() {
        self.psubject.onNext(1)
    }
}
```

I build the framework as an XCFramework and import it into a host app.
In the app I simply instantiate the FWSupplier in a view controller and call triggerPublish and it crashes.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
    let supplier = FWSupplier()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        supplier.triggerPublish()
    }
}
```

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?
[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqDb8.png)
[Screenshot of stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waI8U.png)

Comment: A crash log most likely says what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @adis added screenshots

Comment: @iOSDevZ did you get any solution?? I am facing the same issue.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @AnkitGoyal sadly the only solution that worked for me was removing Publish/Behavior subjects.

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix `release` and `debug`. When you build XCFramework, it depends on the `release` version `rxswift`. When you build the host app, it uses the `debug` version `rxswift`. There is some `#if Debug` in the `rxswift` source code，mixing `release` and `debug` may cause a crash. Instead, you should build the `release` version `rxswift` framework and add it to the `podspec.vendored_frameworks`.